# Where Does Music.app Store Classical Work/Movement Information?

Tags: macos, catalina, music.app, id3-tag

Apple's **Music.app** allows for tagging the *Work Name*, *Movement Number*, and *Movement Title* of a classical track. Where does it store this data?

I read a post from a couple of years ago that said it was shoehorned into the *Grouping* tag, but that no longer appears to be the case. I set the work and movement tags for a track then viewed the track's tags with **ExFalso**. **ExFalso** displays all of a track's tags. There were no tags for work or movement, and the information I entered for those tags did not appear in any other tags.

Is **Music.app** only storing the work and movement tags in the `Library.musicdb` file? Is it supposed to be storing the tags in the song file? Does anyone know how it's handling this data?